# Pointer/memory arithmetic in Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to get a hold of assembly, but there's one probably very simple thing I don't understand.

Consider this following simple example

```
long long * values = new long long[2];
values[0] = 10;
values[1] = 20;

int j = -1;

values[j+2] = 15;  // xxxxxxx
```

Now, the last line (marked with xxxxxx) disassembles to:

```
000A6604  mov         eax,dword ptr [j]  
000A6607  mov         ecx,dword ptr [values]  
000A660A  mov         dword ptr [ecx+eax*8+10h],0Fh
```

First question: What is actually stored in eax and ecx, is it the actual values (i.e. -1 for "j", and the two long long values 10 and 20 for "values"), or is it merely a memory address (e.g. someting like &p, &values) pointing to some place where the values are being stored?

Second question, I know what the third line is supposed to do, but I'm not quite sure why this actually works.
So my understand is, it copies the value 0x0F into the specified memory location. The memory location is basically
- the location of the first element stored in ecx
- plus the size of long long in bytes (= 8) * the value of eax (which equals j, so -1)
- plus the generic offset of 16 bytes (2 times the size of long long).
What I don't get is: In this expression, ecx seems to be a memory address, while eax seems to be a value (-1). How is this possible? Seeing they were defined in pretty much the same way, shouldn't eax and ecx either both contain memory addresses, or both values?

Thanks.

Comment: A memory address and a value are both just bits. The only difference is in what those bits represent.

Comment: Regarding the first question: it's loading the values of `j` and `values` respectively. The value of `values` is _in turn_ the address of a chunk of memory. Writing something like `mov ecx, OFFSET values` would be like taking the address of a pointer in C, which gives you a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Notice that `j` and `values` have different types in your C code too.

Comment: Ahh of course, that makes sense. j = -1, but values = a memory address. I was confusing values with *values. Okay, i think this explains both questions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`eax` and `ecx` are registers -- the first two instructions load those registers with the values used in the calculation, i.e. `j` and `values` (where `values` means the base address of the array by that name).

> I know what the third line is supposed to do, but I'm not quite sure why this actually works

The instruction `mov dword ptr [ecx+eax*8+10h],0Fh` means move the value 0Fh (i.e. 15 decimal) into the location `ecx+eax*8+10h`. To figure that out, consider each piece:

- `ecx` is the base address of the `values` array
- `eax` is the value at `j`, i.e. -1
- `eax*8` is `j` converted to an offset in bytes -- the size of a `long long` is 8 bytes
- `eax*8+10h` 10h is 16 decimal, i.e. 2*8, so this is `j+2` converted to a byte offset
- `ecx+eax*8+10h` adds that final offset to the base address of the array to determine the location in which to store the value 15

Comment: Very good answer, thank you! One last question, how does it "know" j (or eax, respectively) is signed? The definition of j was  "mov dword ptr [j],0FFFFFFFFh". So 0xFFFFFFFF equates to 4,294,967,295 if interpreted as an unsigned number (and indeed, that's what the watch window in VC is telling me). But I assume 4,294,967,295 * 8 would cause an overflow, or yield anything but not -8 as supposed to. So how does this work?!

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF * 8` is `0x7FFFFFFF8`, which is indeed too large to fit in a 32-bit number (i.e. a pointer), so only the least significant 32 bits are used. That leaves us with `0xFFFFFFF8`, i.e. -8 decimal. Add `2*8` to that and you get `0x00000008`, which is the right amount to add to `values` to get the address of `values[-1+2]`.

Comment: Great, got it. How does it know 0xFFFFFFF8 stands for -8, though, and not for 4,294,9672,88? E.g. signed int a = -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF, and unsigned int b = 4294967295 = 0xFFFFFFFF. But accessing values[a+1] and values[b+1] emits the same Assembly code; so how does it know whether then to access element 0, or element 4,294,967,296?

Comment: The processor doesn't "know" -- it's all just bits. The compiler (more specifically, the folks who wrote the compiler) knows how to use 2's complement arithmetic to implement negative numbers. You might have to play with some examples to really understand. First, make sure you know how to use 2's complement (i.e. invert all the bits and add 1). Example: `0x12345678 - 0x8` == `0x12345678 + 0xFFFFFFF8` == `0x112345670`, which is just `0x12345670` if you're limited to the least significant 32 bits.

Comment: What seems to be missing is a 'mov dword ptr [ecx+eax*8+14h],00h', to zero out the upper half of values[j+2], since it's a long long (64 bit or qword).

Comment: @rcgldr Depending on how the array was created (e.g. with something like `calloc()`), the compiler might have determined that that memory was already zeroed out.